# How to check module where a function come from?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running script in the Spyder IPython console as below:

```
In [12]: mydf['logintimes'].count()
Out[12]: 40
```

As I import several modules:

```
import numpy
import pandas
import matplotlib
import scipy.stats
```

Is `count()` a python function, pandas function or `numpy` function?
I tried <kbd>Ctrl+I</kbd> in Spyder, but no documentation was available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U9-Forward is correct, you should normally know it.
However, thanks to python's introspection features, you can also retrieve that information from the objects themselves:

```
>>> s = pandas.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> s.count.__qualname__
'Series.count'
>>> s.count.__module__
'pandas.core.series'
```

Or for built-in list object, note the lack of `__module__`.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l.count.__qualname__
'list.count'
>>> l.count.__module__
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to know it, it is a python function and also a pandas function, you can see it by this:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 3]
>>> l.count(3) # python function
2
```

And a pandas function:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 3])
>>> s.count()
4
```